# Convertir texto a HTML en Vue

Tags: html, css, css3, vue.js, vue3

Tengo un problema y es que mediante el uso de las props mando una propiedad title a un componente que la recibe, el problema es que necesito añadir un salto de línea a la propiedad de title. para que no me quede así:
[image: Titulo erróneo por que se ve la etiqueta]

Necesito añadir el salto de línea y no se como hacerlo.

Comment: y si lo mandas con el salto de linea no lo realiza? creo seria algo asi Titulo de \nla sección

Comment: ¿Probaste con `<br />`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saludos esto puedes realizarlo a traves de la directiva de Vue `v-html`

component.vue

```
   <template>
    <div id="component-1">
       <h1 v-html="propTitle" ></h1>
    </div>  
   </template>
```

de esta forma puede agregar saltos de linea y cualquier otra etiqueta html valida a traves de una prop.

Por si le interesa saber mas:
https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-html